# How do I watch multiple solidity events from the same JS file?

Tags: solidity, javascript

I am unable to watch multiple solidity events from the same JS file. I know the problem is not with either one of the events because they work individually, just not when several `watch()` functions are present. Here is my code:

```
...

function solidityEventListener() {
 let solidityEvent1;
 let solidityEvent2;
 Contract.deployed().then(function(i) {
  solidityEvent1 = i.productCreated({fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'});
  solidityEvent2 = i.productPurchased({fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'});

  solidityEvent1.watch(function(err, result) {
   if (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return;
   }
   createProduct(result.args);
  });

  solidityEvent2.watch(function(err, result) {
   if (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return;
   }
   updateProduct(result.args);
  });
 })
}
```

Only `solidityEvent1` will fire if both `watch()` functions are present. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still unaware what has caused the issue but I was able to resolve it.

Simply `watch()` for `allEvents` and then manually filter which event has been caught. So the above code now looks something like this:

```
...

function solidityEventListener() {
 let solidityEvent;
 Contract.deployed().then(function(i) {
  solidityEvent = i.allEvents({fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'});

  solidityEvent.watch(function(err, result) {
   if (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return;
   }
   // insert if statements to check which event has been caught
  });
 })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in when declaring the Event `var UpdateEvent = Contract.eventToWatch({}, 'latest');`

Comment: It still yields the same issue; only the first watch() function appears to be active.

Answer (score 0):

Using web3.js v0.2, you could use a filter object - if you what to filter for multiple events you must pass in a list within a list. For the following two events emitted in a Solidity contract:

```
event event1(uint256 indexed anumb)
event event2(uint256 indexed anothernumb)
event event3(uint256 indexed yetanothernumb)
```

Use the following to filter for events1 and event2 only:

```
const filter = web3.eth.filter({
  fromBlock: 0,
  toBlock: 'latest',
  address: contractAddress,
  topics: [[web3.sha3('event1(uint256)'),web3.sha3('event2(uint256)')]]
})

filter.get((error, result) => {
   // gets all prior results
})
```

or

```
filter.watch((error, result) => {
   // 
})
```

From the [docs](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#parameters-30):

> topics: Array of Strings - An array of values which must each appear
>   in the log entries. The order is important, if you want to leave
>   topics out use null, e.g. [null, '0x00...']. You can also pass another
>   array for each topic with options for that topic e.g. [null,
>   ['option1', 'option2']]